# MongoDB text index won't return proper results in some cases

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have a very strange issue with a MongoDB database. I have a collection with almost 10.000 records. It has one compound index and one regular.

Compound index:

```
{
    is_archived: 1,
    name: 'text',
    ean: 'text',
    model: 'text',
    mpn: 'text',
    upc: 'text',
    notes: 'text'
}
```

Regular:

```
{
    is_archived: 1
}
```

Say there is a record like this in the collection:

```
{
    is_archived: false,
    name: 'String1 string2 string3 string4'
    ean: '',
    model: '',
    mpn: '',
    upc: '',
    notes: ''    
  }
```

A query like this (with the goal to return all documents that contain all of these words in any order):

```
db.collection.find({
    is_archived: false,
    $text: {
        $search: '"String1""string2""string3""string4"'
    }
})
```

will return the above document.

A query like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    is_archived: false,
    $text: {
        $search: '"String1""string2"'
    }
})
```

will return the above document.

A query like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    is_archived: false,
    $text: {
        $search: '"string2""string3"'
    }
})
```

will return the above document.

A query like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    is_archived: false,
    $text: {
        $search: '"String1""string3"'
    }
})
```

**won't** return the above statement.

The same issue happens with other documents as well but not with all documents.

- I'm running version 2.* of MongoDB. The same database on a newer version has the same problem.
- I tried to replicate it on a new database without success.
- I tried to reindex/delete and recreate the indexes without any luck.

I would like to ask two questions:

- Have you ever seen this before? Does it make any sense?
- What's the proper way to debug this issue? Should I use `explain`?

Thank you guys, this issue is really driving me crazy.

Comment: See if [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) can help you out.

Comment: Thank you @Shrabanee. I don't think there is something wrong with the queries. Otherwise all of the queries would return nothing. In this case some queries work and some doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the phrase search makes an OR search on all the specified keywords, i.e. it will look for documents which contains either the keywords String1, String2, String3 or String4

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "String1 String3"}}, {score: {$meta: "text Score"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"text Score"}})
```

I think you were missing the space in between String1 and String3.

Comment: My goal is to search for any document that has all of these words in any order. This is the purpose of the quotes. Spaces also wont change anything. Thanks